# Folding lists in vimwiki with custom folding enabled

Tags: folding, plugin-vimwiki

[vimwiki's help docs](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/619f04f89861c58e5a6415a4f83847752928252d/doc/vimwiki.txt#L1490), and [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2370/vimwiki-cant-fold-list-items/2372#2372), both explain how
setting `g:vimwiki_folding='list'` in my vimrc enables list folding for vimwiki files. This lets me use vim's native folding methods on vimwiki lists (e.g., `zM` to fold sublist items, `zr` to open folds, etc.)

```
let g:vimwiki_folding='list'
```

But a [few lines down](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/619f04f89861c58e5a6415a4f83847752928252d/doc/vimwiki.txt#L1542) in the docs, I've followed instructions to enable blank lines between folded sections (which I prefer for readability), which required me to add the following to my vimrc:

```
let g:vimwiki_folding='custom'

function! VimwikiFoldLevelCustom(lnum)
  let pounds = strlen(matchstr(getline(a:lnum), '^#\+'))
  if (pounds)
    return '>' . pounds  " start a fold level
  endif
  if getline(a:lnum) =~? '\v^\s*$'
    if (strlen(matchstr(getline(a:lnum + 1), '^#\+')))
      return '-1' " don't fold last blank line before header
    endif
  endif
  return '=' " return previous fold level
endfunction

augroup VimrcAuGroup
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType vimwiki setlocal foldmethod=expr |
    \ setlocal foldenable | set foldexpr=VimwikiFoldLevelCustom(v:lnum)
augroup END
```

Of course, the line `let g:vimwiki_folding='custom'` overwrites the earlier setting of `'list'`, so I lose list folding.

What can I do to keep my custom folding, but also re-enable list folding? Is there an edit I can make to the `VimwikiFoldLevelCustom` function to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You may have more luck with the vimwiki maintainers; at any rate, if you could [edit] to include more details (from the help, the answer, or just code from what you're trying to accomplish), that would help make the question more self-contained. Leave the links, but we want to avoid link-rot and make it easier to see all the details in one place.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've updated the question. I came here first as there's quite a lot of open issues on their GitHub repo, so I figured I might get an answer faster here. But I'll head over there if there's no solution here soon.